# как обработать нажатие по mapicon?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windowsphone

```
<my:MapControl 
                        x:Name="myMapControl"
                        MapServiceToken=" ***" Loaded="myMapControl_Loaded" ZoomLevelChanged="myMapControl_ZoomLevelChanged"
                       >
                        <Button Name="ZoomOut" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="60" Width="60" Click="ZoomOut_Click" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,-9,0,0" />
                    </my:MapControl>



  private void AddMapIcon(float lat, float lon, string title)
        {
            MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
            MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = lat, Longitude = lon });
            MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
            MapIcon1.Title = title;
            MapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + dl.urlimg));
            myMapControl.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
        }
```

как обработать нажатие по mapicon? В документации нашел https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.mapelementclick.aspx 
но не нашел такое событие там где оно должно быть.

Comment: Click="ZoomOut_Click" - это вам не о чем не говорит? К тому же давать куски, выдернутые, не совсем гуд.

Comment: Ну я же не буду весь проект скидывать... То что вы написали это что то... если бы я мог добраться до Click я бы не писал сюда... Возможно я вас не верно понял... Я спрашивал как реализовать конкретно на mapicon обработчик нажатия... При чем тут zoomout...

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx#showing_xaml_controls_and_shapes_on_the_map) есть мануал. Если я правильно понял эвент завётся Tapped.